# Jquery attr('id') is not working

Tags: jquery, alert, attr

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(onLoad());

        function onLoad() {
            alert($("#wcontrol_subtable0").attr('id'));
        }
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="form1">
    <div id="wcontrol_pnlMenu">
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table id="wcontrol_subtable0" class="class1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"
                        style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                        <tr id="wcontrol_subtable0_th">
                            <th>
                                Parameters
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It looks like very normal, the issue is that the alert method comes out with "null"!!!!
I don't know what is really going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to **pass** the `onLoad` function to `ready`, **not call** it:

```
$(document).ready(onLoad);
//  no parenthesis ----^
```

Else you will pass the *return value* of `onLoad` to the `ready` method, i.e. `onLoad` is called and that before the DOM is ready.

Comment: @Lug: You're welcome :) Remember, functions are first class citizens in JavaScript. You can reference them just by name. Adding parenthesis will call them.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the **return value** of `onLoad` in the ready event.

This means that the `onLoad` function is called *immediately* (to find out what the returnv alue is) and the element that you are looking for does not exist (since the DOM for that element hasn't been constructed that that time).

Take the `()` off to pass the function instead of its return value.